# What is the name of this website design style which almost look like MacOS inspired

Tags: website-design, style-identification, trends

[image]

I am just a front end design buff. Now a days I am observing website design looking like Apple's UI design for it's mac and ios applications, but not able to find any article or tutorial explaining this design trend or design kit.

Here ~are~ ~some~ websites which uses such theme:
Only this looks like that  https://coolors.co/

These are different (but I wanted to know even about them):
https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/if-the-probability-density-function-of-a-random-variable-is/
https://supernotes.app/pricing/

Comment: I don't see how your links have *anything* to do with an "Apple UI appearance".

Comment: @Scott, I was thinking OP meant [**the Big Sur (button) look**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK7kp.jpg), which looks *quite* similar to the screenshot, but looking at all of the links, I think OP just means the "flat & rounded" look...

Comment: Not sure that's Apple though @Joonas I mean, Bootstrap was using it long before Big Sur. If anything, I'd say most of the links are just bootstrap defaults.

Comment: @Scott, I'm pretty sure Apple never invented much of anything...

Comment: @Joonas yeah the [image you shared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK7kp.jpg) is really quite similar. My main intention was to know about the design displayed in the screenshot. What's defining is the kind of padding and round buttons and shadows used in the UI that is making it look similar to a MacOS UI

Answer (score 0):

The general term for this is "flat design". Meaning an absence of chrome UI like bevels and a generally soft appearance, without hard black lines between content areas.

Comment: Hmm, but there are several different variations of flat design.

Comment: I think the graphic design community couldn't evolve *academic* names for design trends in **web design or software UI**, only most ~~popular~~ distinct ones like neumorphism, photorealism, skeuomorphism could register themselves as distinct design styles.

Comment: Please do point me to any source which could give an enlightment if I am incorrect about my opinion